# MongoDB : Group different fields with same value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to perform an aggregate on a mongodb collection. But I can't find the correct aggregation pipeline.

In fact, I need to get Ids of **different documents** when `field1 == field2` (field1 not in the same document than field 2).

For example I want to find all documents when the source is the same than the target : `document1.fieldX == document2.fieldY`

It about finding the target server by port numbers.

**Sample docs:**

```js
[ 
  {
    id: 444,
    name: 'Server 1'
    portSource: 1,
    portTarget: 7,
  },
  {
    id: 555,
    name: 'Server 2'
    portSource: 7,
    portTarget: 1
  },
  {
    id: 666,
    name: 'Server 3'
    portSource: 1,
    portTarget: 8
  },
   {
    id: 777,
    name: 'Server 4'
    portSource: 3,
    portTarget: 5
  },
 {
    id: 888,
    name: 'Server 5'
    portSource: 5,
    portTarget: 3
  },
]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[
 {
  portSource: 1, portTarget: 7, sourceId : 444, targetId: 555
 },
 {
  portSource: 3, portTarget: 5, sourceId : 777, targetId: 888
 }
]
```

---

Edit:

**Note 1**: The server with `id: 666` is not returned because any other server match with his target port.

**Note 2**: A correct output can be also like this :

(Reversed target/source)

```
[
 {
  portSource: 7, portTarget: 1, sourceId : 555, targetId: 444
 },
 {
  portSource: 5, portTarget: 3, sourceId : 888, targetId: 777
 }
]
```

Or it can contains twice (The normal way and the reversed) :

```
[
 {
  portSource: 1, portTarget: 7, sourceId : 444, targetId: 555
 },
 {
  portSource: 7, portTarget: 1, sourceId : 555, targetId: 444
 },
 {
  portSource: 3, portTarget: 5, sourceId : 777, targetId: 888
 },
 {
  portSource: 5, portTarget: 3, sourceId : 888, targetId: 777
 }
]
```

Comment: For port 1 you've two sources 444 & 666, but in response how did you get only 444 as sourceId ?

Comment: Effectively, my example is ambiguous, in fact these documents are servers and just only one item can be linked to one port. And The result of the query must be the key pair [1,7]. I Edited my post to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Don't you need that doc with `id :666` returned ? Also how do return only like this : `{
  portSource: 1, portTarget: 7, sourceId : 444, targetId: 555
 }` instead of `{
  portSource: 7, portTarget: 1, sourceId : 555, targetId: 444
 }`

Comment: I don't need `id :666` because any target  server match with this document.

Comment: A correct output can include `{ portSource: 1, portTarget: 7, sourceId : 444, targetId: 555 }`  **or**  `{ portSource: 7, portTarget: 1, sourceId : 555, targetId: 444 }` or **both** of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) stage of aggregation pipeline on same collection :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "collectionName", /** Same collection name */
        let: { portSource: "$portSource" }, /** create a local variable 'portSource' from value of 'portSource' of current doc in lookup stage */
        pipeline: [ /** pipline helps to execute aggregation stages */
          { $match: { $expr: { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$portTarget", "$$portSource" ] }, { $eq: [ "$portSource", "$$portTarget" ] } ] } } }, /** match to filter docs */
          { $project: { id: 1, _id: 0 } } /** project only `id` of matched doc in a new field `targetId` */
        ],
        as: "targetId" /** will be an array, will be empty if none matches (In your case, mostly will be empty or array of single object) */
      }
    },
    /** Only Pairs will have `targetId` non-empty, removing docs where `targetId` array is empty */
    { $match: { targetId: { $ne: [] } } },
    /** create a new field `sourceId` from value of existing field `id`,
     *  re-create `targetId` from value of first elements `id` field in `targetId` array,
     *  You won't find this field for the doc where none of the docs matches for given `portSource` */
    {
      $addFields: { sourceId: "$id", targetId: {  $arrayElemAt: [ "$targetId.id", 0 ] } }
    },
    /** Removing un-necessary field */
    {
      $project: { id: 0 }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AAY2bkBgHFD)